# Error when loading package after installation

Tags: r

I have the 3.2.5 console version of R and I still keep have continuous frustrations because there are still times when various packages I need won't install properly. The current package I've installed is *gmodels* and when I load it in the library (which this is a common message) it reads out this:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘gdata’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gmodels’
```

If there is anyone who could be of assistance I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The solution is in the error message.  Reading `help(install.packages)`, specifically the `dependencies` argument, will guide you to the answer.

Comment: How are you installing these packages? This really shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Packages have dependencies on other packages. When you install some packages, you require to install others in order to use it. In your case, you cannot use gmodels until you have installed gdata.